# CoInitialize() / CoUninitialize() calls pairing

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, com-interop

I have a single-threaded application that uses COM objects. At the beginning I in effect call [`CoInitialize(0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678543(VS.85).aspx) twice - once in my code and the second time in the code of another subsystem of the application. The first call returns `S_OK`, the second returns `S_FALSE` - exactly as MSDN says.

When the application stops it calls `CoUninitialize()` twice but between those calls it tries to call methods of some COM objects - those calls just crash with access violation because I suppose the COM objects are finalized and released at the first call to `CoUnitialize()`. If I remove the duplicating calls to `CoInitialize()`/`CoUnitialize()` it works allright.

But why is this? MSDN says I can call `CoInitialize()` repeatedly and must only pair those calls with the matching number of `CoUnitialize()` calls.

Why are COM objects finalized at the first call to `CoUninitialize()`.

Comment: Out of curiosity why is it you *want* it to work the way you have it implemented - why not just one pair?

Comment: That other subsystem is sometimes used by other programs and it's ugly to demand that they call CoInitialize(), so the subsystem calls it itself before creating the first COM object it will use.

Comment: I can't say *why* it won't work, but i've seen similar issues and always went back to having just one CoUninitialize - no doubt you've already considered (as a hack-workaround) keeping track of the CoInitialize returning S_FALSE and not calling CoUnitialize.

Comment: In my experience it is unwise for individual components to initialize COM themselves, specifically because you run into issues like this.  It is much better design to force the client to initialize COM.

Comment: I looked on XP SP3, CoUninitialize is reference counted, other than calling NotifyInitializeSpies (empty list on my machine), it only decrements the reference count on the first call.  Set a break point on _CoUninitialize@0 to verify some else isn't calling it an extra time.  I assume you're not calling it right after CoInit() returns  S_FALSE.

Comment: @Luke you are completely right. Not only must you ensure that you properly reference count and test for RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE error. You have to deal with "the first thread in the application that calls CoInitialize with 0 (or CoInitializeEx with COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED) must be the last thread to call CoUninitialize". And the nail in coffin is if library code initializes COM then the library forces upon the client the the mode COM operates in. COM is one of those resource that breaks constructor destructor model.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you're doing it correct, however, check to be sure your couninitialize calls are done after the main window for the app has closed and after the message loop for that window has run finished.

Comment: can you move it outside the loop? that might help.

Comment: Actually that's not easy. Why does it matter in the first place?

Comment: it only matters because i found some documentation (an older help file) that says to do that. not sure if it will fix the problem. kind of makes sense, though.

Comment: @Don Dickinson: I don't get why this is relevant to the problem at all.

Comment: it is only relevant because the helpfile i read on it (an older one that came with delphi) is very specific about it. it says to call counitialize after the message loop has finished.