# COM Initialization and Use in Win32 C++ DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, com

I am writing a Win32 C++ DLL that uses the COM to query WMI.  How can I programmatically determine if COM has already been initialized?  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Mark Ransom is right**
the straightforward, clean and simple solution is to require COM initialization by the caller.

**Ugly hack**
You can try your first call - likely `CoCreateInstance`, and if it returns CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED, run `CoInitialize` yourself (and don't forget to uninit in that case)

*However*, it is still problematic to "inject" a CoInitialize into a caller thread from a DLL. So there's a

**Clean Solution**
Let the DLL create a worker thread (which means the DLL needs Init and Teardown calls), CoInitializeEx in this thread yourself, and move all the COM calls to that separate thread.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a worker thread.  Initialization and tear-down are all done in the same DLL function.  `WaitForSingleObject` is used to wait for the worker thread to complete.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is not to bother, just make it a requirement of anybody using your DLL that they initialize COM first. Otherwise you run the risk of messing up their own initialization if they perform it *after* yours.

On the other hand if your flags to `CoInitializeEx` match those of the application, you should be fine. From the [`CoInitializeEx` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms695279(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Multiple calls to CoInitializeEx by
>   the same thread are allowed as long as
>   they pass the same concurrency flag,
>   but subsequent valid calls return
>   S_FALSE.

Comment: That is really not helpful.  Unfortunately, most of the application is already written.  I need to know how to determine if the COM has already been initialized.  I realize this is not best practice, but it's what have to work with.

Comment: @Jim:  This is right.  Just always CoInitializeEx() exactly once and CoUninitialize() exactly once in your code.  It doesn't and shouldn't matter if it has already been called in your thread.  Besides which, you don't control when the code you downt control will un-init COM, so relying on the initialization state when you start up is dangerous.

Comment: +1, Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2154151/57428 - looks like calling `CoInitialize()` more that once can lead to some weird problems.

Answer (score 2):

It follows @peterchen clean [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4455931/213871) as I coded it for a thread-safe COM logger component that I wanted to wrap:

```
IComLoggerPtr _logger;
_bstr_t _name;
HANDLE _thread;
HANDLE _completed;

Logger::Logger(_bstr_t name)
{
    _name = name;
    
    _completed = ::CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, NULL);
    if (_completed == NULL)
        ::AtlThrowLastWin32();

    // Launch the thread for COM interation
    DWORD threadId;
    _thread = ::CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)(this->threadRun),
        (LPVOID)this, 0, &threadId);

    // Wait object initialization
    HRESULT hr = ::WaitForSingleObject(_completed, INFINITE);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        AtlThrow(hr);
}

Logger::~Logger()
{
    ::SetEvent(_completed);
    CloseHandle(_thread);
    CloseHandle(_completed);
}

DWORD WINAPI Logger::threadRun(LPVOID opaque)
{
    Logger *obj = (Logger *)opaque;

    // Init Free-Threaded COM subsystem
    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        ::AtlThrow(hr);

    hr = obj->_logger.CreateInstance(__uuidof(ComLogger));
    if (FAILED(hr))
        ::AtlThrow(hr);

    obj->_logger->Init(obj->_name);

    // Initialization completed
    bool success = ::SetEvent(obj->_completed);
    if (!success)
        ::AtlThrowLastWin32();

    // Wait release event
    hr = ::WaitForSingleObject(obj->_completed, INFINITE);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        AtlThrow(hr);

    obj->_logger.Release();
    
    // Release COM subsystem
    ::CoUninitialize();
}

HRESULT Logger::Log(_bstr_t description)
{
    return _logger->Log(description);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CoInitializeEx\CoUninitialize should only be called by threads (not by Dll-calls).

BTW ,you should not Use CoInitializeEx\CoUninitialize in DllMain !